# Как формируется урл страницы товара в интернет-магазинах?

Tags: url, интернет-магазин

Заметил, что во многих интернет-магазинах урл товара содержит 7 или 8-значную цифровую последовательность:
спортмастер /product/10523032/
валдбериз /catalog/6254964/detail.aspx
связной /catalog/audiovideo/1558/5761214 (1558- это у них вообще подкатегория)
ситилинк /catalog/mobile/cell_phones/1391508/
Мое предположение:
1-й вариант - для формирования такого урла используется id товара и в базе данных сразу задается начальный id, равный 10'000'000, таким образом все последующие id получаются одинаковой длины и таких id достаточно много, почти 90 млн.
2-й вариант - урл формируется через промежуточную таблицу, исчисляясь по некоей формуле)))
**Вопрос: 1 или 2?**

Comment: Урл формируется в зависимости от того какую идею заложил разработчик. Каких-то общепринятых правил нет. Это может быть мотивированно желанием поддерживать соответствие айди товаров в разных источниках, совместимостью с какими-то сторонними клиентами, сервисами и т.д.

Comment: Может, это вообще что-то вроде артикула, и у каждой цифры в id есть свой особый смысл

Comment: Ибэй туда же - /i/293225739538 - 12 символов...